# What does 'application' mean in the context of AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The AWS documentaion says "Elastic Beanstalk for PHP makes it easy to deploy, manage, and scale your PHP web applications". But what does it mean by 'application' in this context? Does it just mean your project files including php, html, png, .htaccess etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web application (think web site) would be your final solution to be hosted. It would contain everything you've deemed necessary for the application (php files, html, png, .htaccess etc.). So in short, yes! Also that first sentence in the documentation is boilerplate. A web application is going to have the same context across the board when it comes to development and hosting with Elastic Beanstalk.